# replacing for loop by apply call returned list of lists instead of individual objects

Tags: r, lapply

Need to get column names from specific database table and assign to objects to be populated with new data in the next step.

(using postgresql but you can use the RBDMS yoy prefer. The issue is not database but proper use of lapply)

This is perfectly working code:

```
get_colNames_object <- function(x) {

            sqltext <- paste0("dbGetQuery(poscon, \"SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=\'", x,"\' AND table_schema=\'my_schema\'\")" )

            result <- eval(parse(text = sqltext))

            result <- unname(result$column_name)

            assign(x, result, envir = parent.frame()) 
          }
```

this seems to work if you make a function call with one table. The object is returned ok this way:

```
      get_colNames_object("customers")

> customers

     [1] "id"                 "client_id"           "name"            "surname"
```

But.....when calling lapply I get a list of lists instead of individual objects:

```
tablelist <- c("customers", "sales")

lapply(tablelist, get_colNames_object)

[[1]]
[1] "id"                 "client_id"           "name"            "surname"              

[[2]]
[1] "id"                 "product_id"           "price"      "client_id"
```

any hint why this is not working with my list? The expected result is a bunch of objects regarding column names. One for every table in schema.

Comment: Cath if you make this call get_colNames_object("customers") and then get_colNames_object("sales") you get two objects in the environment. Each object is a list of column names assigned to an object with the table name on it.  The expected output is an object for every table.

Comment: Never use `eval(parse(...))` like this. And don't write functions with side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple loop instead of lapply. 
This code worked for me:

```
for (t in tablelist) {

  text_to_parse <- paste0(t ," <- get_colNames_object(\'",t,"\')")

  eval(parse(text = text_to_parse))


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the function `dbListFields` in `DBI` that lets you query the column names ot a table directly. I extended the example from the `dbListFields` help page for your question about using `lapply`

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars2", mtcars)

table_list <- list("mtcars", "mtcars2")

t(sapply(table_list, dbListFields, conn = con))
```

Result:

```
[,1]        [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5] [,6]   [,7] [,8]   [,9] [,10] [,11][,12] 
[1,] "row_names" "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am"  "gear" "carb"
[2,] "row_names" "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am"  "gear" "carb"
```